# Why does Python Tkinter Canvas draw causes a freeze?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, canvas, tkinter

I have written a pice of Code where i have a simple gui with an canvas. On this canvas i draw an matplot. The matplot is updated every second with data from fake sensor data i create in an SQLite DB (just for testing at the moment).

My Problem is that the redrawing of the canvas causes my window/gui to lag every second.

I even tried to update the plot in another thread. But even there i get an lag.

Here the idea without a thread:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime
from random import randint

class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent

        root.update_idletasks()

        f = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)        
        x=1
        ax = f.add_subplot(111)        
        line = ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))        

        def animate(i):
            # Open Database
            conn = sqlite3.connect('Sensor_Data.db')
            c = conn.cursor()
            # Create some fake Sensor Data    
            NowIs = datetime.now()
            Temperature = randint(0, 100)
            Humidity = randint(0, 100)
            # Add Data to the Database
            c = conn.cursor()
            # Insert a row of data
            c.execute("insert into Sensor_Stream_1 (Date, Temperature, Humidity) values (?, ?, ?)",
                        (NowIs, Temperature, Humidity))
            # Save (commit) the changes
            conn.commit()
            # Select Data from the Database
            c.execute("SELECT Temperature FROM Sensor_Stream_1 LIMIT 10 OFFSET (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Sensor_Stream_1)-10") 
            # Gives a list of all temperature values 
            x = 1
            Temperatures = []

            for record in c.fetchall():    
                Temperatures.append(str(x)+','+str(record[0]))
                x+=1
            # Setting up the Plot with X and Y Values
            xList = []
            yList = []

            for eachLine in Temperatures:
                if len(eachLine) > 1:
                    x, y = eachLine.split(',')
                    xList.append(int(x))
                    yList.append(int(y))

            ax.clear()

            ax.plot(xList, yList) 

            ax.set_ylim(0,100)
            ax.set_xlim(1,10)
            ax.grid(b=None, which='major', axis='both', **kwargs)


        label = tk.Label(root,text="Temperature / Humidity").pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=root)
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

        root.ani = animation.FuncAnimation(f, animate, interval=1000)            

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    MainApplication(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

And here my try with another thread:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

import numpy as np

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

import sqlite3

from datetime import datetime
from random import randint

#
from concurrent import futures
from time import sleep, time
#

class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent

        root.geometry('1280x720')
        root.update_idletasks()       

        #GUI
        x = 1
        f = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)
        ax = f.add_subplot(111)        
        line = ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))

        label = tk.Label(root,text="Temperature / Humidity").pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=root)
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

        def animate(i):
            print("hello")
            # Open Database
            conn = sqlite3.connect('Sensor_Data.db')
            c = conn.cursor()
            # Create some fake Sensor Data    
            NowIs = datetime.now()
            Temperature = randint(0, 100)
            Humidity = randint(0, 100)
            # Add Data to the Database
            c = conn.cursor()
            # Insert a row of data
            c.execute("insert into Sensor_Stream_1 (Date, Temperature, Humidity) values (?, ?, ?)",
                        (NowIs, Temperature, Humidity))
            # Save (commit) the changes
            conn.commit()
            # Select Data from the Database
            c.execute("SELECT Temperature FROM Sensor_Stream_1 LIMIT 10 OFFSET (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Sensor_Stream_1)-10") 
            # Gives a list of all temperature values 
            x = 1

            Temperatures = []

            for record in c.fetchall():    
                Temperatures.append(str(x)+','+str(record[0]))
                x+=1
#                
            # Setting up the Plot with X and Y Values
            xList = []
            yList = []

            for eachLine in Temperatures:
                if len(eachLine) > 1:
                    x, y = eachLine.split(',')
                    xList.append(int(x))
                    yList.append(int(y))

            ax.clear()

            ax.plot(xList, yList) 

            ax.set_ylim(0,100)
            ax.set_xlim(1,10)
            ax.grid(b=None, which='major', axis='both', **kwargs)

            canvas.draw()

            root.after(1000, animate, 1000) 


        e = futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)

        e.submit(animate, 1000)           

def on_closing():
    if messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you want to quit?"):
        root.destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    MainApplication(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You already asked this question. If you still need help with your original question then consider using a bounty on it or update your question in your original post.

Comment: Yes, i was quiet unsure, because the info says "only questions no discussion if possible". I will update my first question and put a bounty on it if the 2 days are over. There you said you would take a look on my Code, have you done it already?

Comment: Yes I have been messing with the code but not reached a conclusion yet. I only have a little time to review each post so I try not to focus a large amount of time to any one post. If I have the time today I will continue to play with your code to see where the delay is.

Comment: Thank you very much! 
In the first example i draw the Canvas once and clear the plot and plot i again every time the function runs. In the second i have to draw the canvas each time the function runs (maybe a bad solution).